# generating controllers/actions in Zend

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, content-management-system

I'm planning on coding a little basic cms and got some questions.

Imagen you have a Navigation like this:

```
Home --> www.foo.com/home
About Us --> www.foo.com/about_us
Contact --> www.foo.com/contact
```

Each of them are a controller and sub navigation could be actions. Imagen now, you have a button "Add Navigationpoint" so a user can add a new page. He will add the page "News", so now I'd need to create a controller and an index action and maybe some other actions.

Basically, this is no problem. I could just generate a string and create the file. But whats the nice way? Somehow i think, this is wrong.

Note: I don't want to use any databases. Also i will try to change the views from .phtml to .html and use js. Passing json from the controller to my view.

The goal is the following: The user should be able to add a new page, type in the template of that page, add a css and some js files. I'll save the whole homepage structure on the filesystem.

My idea is to create a helper which checks e.g. if the according view exists. So i don't need controllers and actions at all.

Anyway, I'm quite unsure, hope you understood me.

The reason why i want to have everything within .html files and use JS for templating is, that i want it to be live editable and most designers don't know PHP Syntax. I really like mustache and since mustache needs JSON anyway, why not just use JS. Also i really like JS more then PHP. And the whole thing should be a little challenge, never done anything like this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not generating code controllers/actions for new "user submitted" pages.

I would suggest using a single controller for rendering/creating any "user submitted" pages.

For example the url could look like this:

`News --> www.foo.com/custom/render/news`

Comment: Of course this is an option. I sifference between 2 kinds of actions. The ones which are actual links to a page and others which are just about saving, retrieving etc. Data. My current approach is creating a helper which checks if a a viewscript called the same, in this case 'home' . If so proceed with the custom renderer if there is a script proceed as usual. Hmm but i don't know if this is a good solution. Your solution ia rather bad since there are unessecary infos in the urls. At least i like small urls :) thanks for the input

Comment: To adjust the URL's you can use: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.usage

Comment: Atm, i don't know how a router should help me here since the formats of my urls are the same. E.g. you have foo.com/news/index and foo.com/json/get. The first one is a link to some visual page and the second one is just for getting some data, technical thing. Haven't worked a lot with routes yet, the only thing i've done was multi language stuff, but there you just check for different url formats. Anyway, I'll read about it. I also thought of making that what you've said together with rewrite rules. Rewriting foo.com/news to www.foo.com/custom/render/news